# How to use Image.file and Image.asset in the same list?

Tags: flutter

My friends, I am developing a sports app. An application where you can set up your own football team. When you click on the boxes, it lists the players and when you click on the player you choose, it comes into the container.
I have done this with Image.asset and I am displaying the players with GridView.

Now, what I want is for people using the application to choose a photo from their phone and be included in that list. However, when I do it with Image.file, it does not appear in the list. What path should I follow?

Answer (score 0):

try Use this package called Path Provider from https://pub.dev..

https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

it will give you access and you have various location to put your assets accordingly... Try this it will let you help out from your issue

Comment: If I can't can i ask you again? 